# Python SUDS not giving description of WebFault

Tags: suds

I am creating all the attributes properly and I know that my request is complete because it is giving a `TypeError` when I add any extraneous fields that my web service does not accept. Now when I call the Method like `client.service.Method(attributes...)` I get a `WebFault` but there is no description for why the WebFault is occurring. Has anyone faced this problem before or does anyone know what this could mean?

The traceback is:

```
File "C:/Python25/sudsfirst.py", line 34, in <module>
    result = client.service.Method(arg1,arg2)
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\client.py", line 542 in __call__
    return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\client.py", line 602, in invoke
    result = self.send(soapenv)
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\client.py", line 649, in send
    result = self.failed(binding, e)
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\bindings\binding.py", line 265, in get_fault
    raise WebFault(p, faultroot)
WebFault
```

The code is:

```
url = 'http://blah?wsdl'
client = Client(url)
arg1 = client.factory.create('type1')
arg1.type1 = ...
arg2 = client.factory.create('type2')
arg2.type1 = ...
client.service.Method(arg1, arg2)
```

Sorry, I can't mention more than this about the code.

Comment: Please post the code and the traceback.

Comment: You should have posted that in the question.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this..but learning it the hard way :P